# Hostinger: unfinished action is running wait until it is finished

Tags: github, deployment, hosting

I have connected my hostinger account with my GitHub, and I wanted to deploy my Laravel project.
I have deployed my project by clicking on deploy button in Git tab in hostinger then i deleted all files using hostinger file manager because it was in subdomain.
Then I clicked the deploy button but before the deployment is finished I deleted the folder again using hostinger file manager.
Since then, i get the ‘Unifished action is running please wait until it is finished’ error message.
I tried to click on the ‘stop running process’ in account tab and I also clicked on the reset button in the account tab, but still i get the same error message.
I tried to check my account after a hour or two, but its the same.

When i click on reset, stop running process, deploy, create website using website builder and every other buttons, but still the error message show at the top right corner and says ‘unfinished action is running please wait until it is finished’.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, click on the ‘stop running process’ in the **account** tab, maybe it will help you.
If this doesn’t help you then try to contact the support team.